# How to add a combobox as TreeViewItem in TreeView, wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying programmatically (C#) to put a ComboBox inside a TreeViewItem in WPF. 
Is it really possible to do this or TreeViewItem serves only for string values (Header attribute)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can add almost anything to a TreeView. However, it's not a good idea to do this in code but if you really want to achieve this you can use this code:

XAML:

```
        <TreeView Name="tree">

        </TreeView>
```

CODE:

```
        //Adding a test item
        TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
        tvi.Header = "ImAStandardTreeViewItem";

        //adding a ComboBox
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
        cbi.Content = "WuhuImInAComboBox";
        cb.Items.Add(cbi);

        //add them to TreeView
        this.tree.Items.Add(tvi);
        this.tree.Items.Add(cb);
```

If you want to do this the right way you need to dig into MVVM and data templating

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: if you find this helpful please mark it as answer for other users to find it @user253105